# Magento 2 get total_ordered_qty and total_qty_shipped

Tags: magento-2.1

How to get the total ordered qty and total shipped qty on phtml by order_id?

Comment: I post answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get total order item qty by using this code.

```
$order_id = 5; //PASS YOUR ORDER ID HERE
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($order_id);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
$total_qty = 0;
foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
  $total_qty = $total_qty + $item->getQtyOrdered();
} 

echo $total_qty;
```

Above code give you total qty order in this order.

Comment: yeah thank you I tried this and it worked :)